# Convert day of week and time to other timezone

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, timezone

I am going to set up and manage some cron jobs for users from different  time zones. One of the possible way for settings is to run task at particular days of week at particular time, e.g.:

```
On Sat,Sun at 22:00 AM
```

For each user I have his timezone (e.g, `'America/New_York'`, `'Europe/Berlin'`, etc). So what is the best way to convert day of week and time to other timezone (my server's timezone) to set up cron job.

```
 $date = new DateTime("this saturday 22:00", new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

 $beforeConversion = [
    "dayOfWeek" => $date->format('D'),   // Sat
    "time" => $date->format('H:i')       // 22:00
 ];

 $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

 $beforeConversion = [
    "dayOfWeek" => $date->format('D'),   // Sun
    "time" => $date->format('H:i')       // 02:00
 ];
```

I came up with the code presented above. Is it the best and optimal way to do this kind of stuff in PHP?

Comment: What do you want to happen if after the conversion the day is different?

Comment: @Dhaman just need to get the day of week and time

Comment: Are you looking for a solution like this: https://ideone.com/BTYlzV

Comment: @Dharman not exactly. I updated my question with the solution I came up to.

Comment: It looks like you got things sorted. This is barely 2 lines of code, not counting your formatting. Why are you not happy with this solution? You can chain the methods if you want it to be in one line.